# How to handle onclick event of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button events</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            button{
                background-color: #00FFFF;
                border: 2px solid orange;
                border-radius: 10px;
                width: 60px;
                height: 30px;
                color:white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.lastElementChild.onclick = changeColor;
            function changeColor(){
                if(document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML == "Like"){
                    document.body.lastElementChild.style.background-color = "#FF9966";
                    document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML = "Unlike";    
                }else{
                    document.body.lastElementChild.style.background-color="#00FFFF";
                    document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML = "Like";  
                }
            }
        </script>
        <button type="button" name="LikeUnlike">Like</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

error is thrown at line `document.body.lastElementChild.style.background-color = "#FF9966";`. Error is `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

How do I resolve this error?

*Note: yet to learn JQuery*

Comment: Is there a problem with that? <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to use `element.style.backgroundColor` instead of `element.style.background-color`.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference) is a list of the JS equivalent of CSS attributes.

Your second problem is that your script executed before the `<button>` is loaded, thus making the script the current `lastElementChild`of `body`.

You can solve this by wrapping your script in `window.onload`:

(Also, selecting your button with `document.body.lastElementChild` is bound to give you errors since you most likely at some point will add something after the button)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Button events</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    button {
      background-color: #00FFFF;
      border: 2px solid orange;
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 60px;
      height: 30px;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      
      var likeButton = document.getElementById("like-button");
      likeButton.onclick = changeColor;

      function changeColor() {
        if (likeButton.innerHTML == "Like") {
          likeButton.style.backgroundColor = "#FF9966";
          likeButton.innerHTML = "Unlike";
        } else {
          likeButton.style.backgroundColor = "#00FFFF";
          likeButton.innerHTML = "Like";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <button type="button" name="LikeUnlike" id="like-button">Like</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`background-color` is not a valid JavaScript identifier. For setting it with DOM style object, it should be `backgroundColor` in camel case.

More info on DOM style object at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Answer (score 1):

Check out my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln1m27yo/)

JS

```
document.body.lastElementChild.onclick = changeColor;
            function changeColor(){
                if(document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML == "Like"){
                    document.body.lastElementChild.style.backgroundColor  = "#FF9966";
                    document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML = "Unlike";    
                }else{
                    document.body.lastElementChild.style.backgroundColor ="#00FFFF";
                    document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML = "Like";  
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use  `document.body.lastElementChild.style["background-color"]` to set color for element

Comment: But `document.body.lastElementChild` gives `CSSStyleDeclaration` instance that has property `backgroundColor`. How come your syntax is accepted? Please clarify. I also learnt somewhere that subscript notation is used when property names have hyphen

Answer (score 0):

not background-color but backgroundColor . Try this and see if works
`document.body.lastElementChild.style.backgroundColor = "#FF9966"`;
the total code:

```
document.body.lastElementChild.onclick = changeColor;
    function changeColor(){
        if(document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML == "Like"){
            document.body.lastElementChild.style.backgroundColor  = "#FF9966";
            document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML = "Unlike";    
        }else{
            document.body.lastElementChild.style.backgroundColor ="#00FFFF";
            document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML = "Like";  
        }
    }
```

Comment: But in firefox browser, I see the property name `background-color`

Comment: In the DOM control it changes because background-color means a variable named background minus color

Answer (score 0):

You use this code. It is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button events</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            button{
                background-color: #00FFFF;
                border: 2px solid orange;
                border-radius: 10px;
                width: 60px;
                height: 30px;
                color:white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.lastElementChild.onclick = changeColor;
            function changeColor(){
                if(document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML == "Like"){
                    document.body.lastElementChild.style.backgroundColor = 

"#FF9966";
                    document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML = "Unlike";    
                }else{


document.body.lastElementChild.style.backgroundColor="#00FFFF";
                    document.body.lastElementChild.innerHTML = "Like";  
                }
            }
        </script>
        <button type="button" name="LikeUnlike" onclick="changeColor

()">Like</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery for assign or remove a css class, to add color to your button, with this code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('other-color');
        });
    });
</script>
```

the **toggleClass** function is to add and remove a css class,
"**othercolor**" is your class css with the styles to your button.

Include jquery with this script before `</body>` and before the code above:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function() {
            $('button').on('click', function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('other-color');
            });
        });
</script>
```

I hope it helps you.